# checkbox checked value changing when added to DOM

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm dynamically creating a series of checkboxes based on values pulled from elsewhere and I'm trying to keep the code generic. The checkboxes are in a large UI section in javascript to be added to the DOM in one go to avoid locking the UI as much as possible.

It's required that some of the checkboxes are initially checked, however setting the the value of the HTMLElement to true doesn't work. Once the entire HTML section is appended the checkboxes are no longer checked.

Does anyone know why or have a decent work around?

Here's a small example of how it works

```
addFilter = function (spec, all_vis){ 
     var contain_div = document.createElement('div');
     var visualisation_spec = document.createElement('div');
     for(var i=0;i< all_vis.length; i++) {
         if(contains(spec.vis_list, all_vis[i])){ // This is a custom function 
              var check = document.createElement('input')
              check.type = 'checkbox';
              check.value = all_vis[i];
              check.checked = true;
              visualisation_spec.append(check);
              visualisation_spec.innerHTML += all_vis[i] +"<br>"//this isnt quite how i 
                                                               //create the label 
         }
     }
     contain_div.append(visualisation_spec)
      // .... MORE INTERFACE CREATION 
     ...
     return contain_div;
     // This interface segment is returned and attached to others before being 
     // added to the DOM
}
```

No JQuery please!

Comment: what is `spec` and `contains()`?

Comment: spec is an object that defines the values for the checkboxes and other interface items, contains is just a custom function that checks if an item is in a list. it does a similar job to indexof() but has a few other tweaks to it that aren't relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `setAttribute('checked', true)` - because you use `.checked` it doesn't actually put on an attribute and then because you are mixing it with appending to the `innerHTML`, it may be why you are losing the checked state

`.checked` works without `innerHTML`

```js
var check = document.createElement('input');
check.type = 'checkbox';
check.value = 'test';
check.checked = true

document.body.append(check);
```

With `innerHTML`, checked doesn't work as no attribute has actually been set and it is probably changing existing content to a string to append new content onto:

```js
var check = document.createElement('input');
check.type = 'checkbox';
check.value = 'test';
check.checked = true

document.body.append(check);
document.body.innerHTML += 'test'
```

Setting the attribute manually should work

```js
var check = document.createElement('input');
check.type = 'checkbox';
check.value = 'test';
check.setAttribute('checked', true);

document.body.append(check);
document.body.innerHTML += 'test'
```

Comment: great thanks, that's got it sorted I will try remove all the innerHTML entirely once i get chance I think just to stop it doing anything else unexpected.